# Keep original datetime stored in mysql when using sequelize js

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

The datetime stores correctly in the Mysql DB: "2019-08-04 10:41:53"
Then I use a stored procedure to pull the info in node.js like so:

```
Sequelize.query('CALL getBoardThreads(:boardid,:userid,:page)', {replacements: { boardid : req.params.id, userid : userid, page : req.params.page }})
    .then( result => { console.log(result); });
```

when I view the console, the date is: "2019-08-04T20:41:53.000Z" not sure why, I don't convert, don't have anything special..just a call to the stored procedure which all it has is a select statement with no conversions either.

Here's the config for Sequelize:

```
const config = {
database: process.env.DB_NAME,
username: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASS,
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
dialect: process.env.DB_ENGINE,
dialectOptions: { useUTC: false },
logging: s => debug(s),
setup: true,
pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
    acquire: 30000
},
query: {
    raw: true
},
typeCast: function castField( field, useDefaultTypeCasting ) {

    // We only want to cast bit fields that have a single-bit in them. If the field
    // has more than one bit, then we cannot assume it is supposed to be a Boolean.
    if ( ( field.type === "BIT" ) && ( field.length === 1 ) ) {

        var bytes = field.buffer();

        // A Buffer in Node represents a collection of 8-bit unsigned integers.
        // Therefore, our single "bit field" comes back as the bits '0000 0001',
        // which is equivalent to the number 1.
        return( bytes[ 0 ] === 1 );

    }

    return( useDefaultTypeCasting() );

}}
```

I went ahead and added the dialectOption for utc but still nothing. Also tried:

```
dialectOptions: {
    //useUTC: false, //for reading from database
    //dateStrings: true,
    typeCast: function (field, next) { // for reading from database
        switch(field.type){
            case 'DATETIME':
            case 'TIMESTAMP':
                return new Date(field.string());
                break;
            case 'BIT':
                var bytes = field.buffer();
                return( bytes[ 0 ] === 1 );
                break;
            default:
                return next();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

commented the utc because I kept getting a warning:
"Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration options to a Connection"

Comment: have you tried to add dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false 
  }, under your sequelize config file?

Comment: @feiiiiii No, I'm fairly new to this but I'll check that

Answer (score 2):

It's a good thing, so nothing to worry about it.

> **How it is working:**
>
> Sequlize converts the date and time into UTC format default, and
>   that's a very good thing when you have multiple timezones to handle
>   and it becomes very handy
>
> **This will be you local time** : 2019-08-04 10:41:53
>
> **UTC of your time** : 2019-08-04T20:41:53.000Z

And if you still want to change that :

> **[As per the doc :](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)**
>
> The timezone used when converting a date from the database into a
>   JavaScript date. The timezone is also used to SET TIMEZONE when
>   connecting to the server, to ensure that the result of NOW,
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and other time related functions have in the right
>   timezone. For best cross platform performance use the format +/-HH:MM.
>   Will also accept string versions of timezones used by moment.js (e.g.
>   'America/Los_Angeles'); this is useful to capture daylight savings
>   time changes.

```
const config = {
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.DB_ENGINE,
    "timezone": "Europe/Warsaw" // <------- YOUR TIMEZONE OR "timezone": "+08:00"
    ...
}
```

**My suggestion :**
Use UTC DateTime format and convert the DateTime on the frotend side with a javascript date object, that will convert UTC to local time as per the browser.